# Activate Service Account from GCloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to configure a [notification for a Google Cloud Storage bucket object change](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorization) however I'm stuck when trying to make gsutil use a service account with this command.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account service-account-email --key-file path/to/key.p12
```

The error I get in the command line is:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) PyOpenSSL is not available. If you have already installed PyOpenSSL, you will need to enable site packages by setting the environment variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES to 1. If that does not work, See https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/crypto for details.
```

I followed [this instructions to get pyOpenSSL](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/crypto). If I ask pip about that package it tells me it is installed

```
$ pip show pyopenssl
---
Name: pyOpenSSL
Version: 0.14
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: cryptography, six
```

I also see the environment variable if I call the env command

```
$ env
...
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you verify that OpenSSL is available? Try importing OpenSSL in a python prompt, and if that works, try "$ CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1 gcloud interactive" and "import OpenSSL" in that python prompt. If it succeeds in the first and fails in the second, that will help narrow down the issue. If it fails in the first, PyOpenSSL is not installed properly.

Comment: No, it didn't work. >>> import OpenSSL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
>>> 
. I certainly had problems installing PyOpenSSL with pip on Mac OSX, but I thought everything was OK now.

Comment: My recommendation there is to use a virtualenv, and only use pip to install things into a virtualenv. When running from within a virtualenv there won't be any -S issues (-S is never provided when gcloud is run from a virtualenv).

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that PyOpenSSL was not properly installed. Since PyOpenSSL includes crypto routines, the Cloud SDK can not easily package it and we rely on third-party installation.