# Backing up my GCE instance

Tags: cron, backup, google-compute-engine

I'm finding what I'm trying to do so difficult, I simply must be going about it all wrong.

I've got a Compute instance with just the root persistent disk. I'm just running a little Wordpress server (nginx+php+local mysql) on this so I haven't added any external components. For now this is all self contained.

Now I simply want to run a regular backup of this instance. I learned that this is done through snapshots, and I even tested that and launched a new instance with the snapshot. Makes sense- now I just need to automate that.

I've got a shell script that uses gcutil to take a snapshot and rotate the backups. When I SSH into my instance, this script works fine. Now I just want it to run as a CRON job. When I create a crontab for the logged-in SSH user, the job will run. But I would like to have the job run out of /etc/cron.daily - which runs as root. When cron kicks off, it ends up failing with:

```
You are not currently logged in. To authenticate, run
$ gcloud auth login
```

When I sudo into root and attempt to gcloud auth login, it warns me that I should use a service account. I've tried gcloud config set account to the automatically created service account, and I've tried creating new service accounts as well. None of this is working- I keep getting the auth error. There are lots of docs that say bits and pieces about this- enough to make it look like the puzzle might fit together but everything I'm finding is too vague to simply tell me how create and/or use a service account to invoke GCE from a CRON job.

I simply can't believe its this hard- I'm a pretty savvy tech guy. Am I just trying to use GCE the wrong way?

Finally what I've done is just ignored the warning and authenticated into my account logged from root. The CRON job will run now, but I'm not sure how persistent this login is. Is it permanent? Or will it time out and the backups start failing? I do have it sending email alerts so at least I'll know if its failing.

Clearly I've got a big learning curve to go through here.

Thats the buildup- basically I have two questions:

1- Any pointers to explicit steps for creating and/or using a service account with the command line tools in a shell script / CRON job?

2- Am I not doing it the Google way or missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use gcloud command you need to authorize your access. You can do that either by using a service account or you need to run gcloud auth login command to authorize the current user account to run gcloud commands. When you authorize a user on your linux box by running a gcloud auth login it creates a authorization file in the home directory .config/gcloud/credentials which has OAuth credentials for that user. These credentials are refreshed automatically unless credentials are deleted or automatic refresh fails for some reason. So running this command as root authorized your root account to run gcloud command and your script was working.

You can achieve your setup by creating an instance with a service account scope set to read/write for compute engine. For more info on service account scopes you can [visit](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#aliases). Once you do that all the users on that instance will be able to run gcloud compute command without having to authorize. The following command will help you create an instance with service account scopes for compute engine set to read-write you can find more information on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create):

gcloud compute instances create - create  --scopes compute-rw

Answer (score 0):

Service account is the way to go.  I had the same issue for cron.  Download pk12 file from service account and install as root using gcloud command this should help. [Activate Service Account from GCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682687/activate-service-account-from-gcloud)